# Can I upload a video to Youtube using OpenId + OAuth in behalf of a user which does not have a youtube account but gmail?

Tags: openid, oauth, youtube, gdata-api, youtube-api

I need to develop a web site where I upload videos using the youtube API.
I cannot do it to my youtube account (see youtube terms for an explantion on that) so it need to be done in the user behalf.

It would be great to avoid the user having to register to youtube.
If I use OpenID + OAuth within the youtube API, can a gmail account or other OpenID account be enough ?

Or that the user has a youtube account is a must ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could only upload videos into a YouTube account

See http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/edbabdfe94c85afb